# eclipse why cannot set breakpoint in static block code

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

Maven project have a dependency jar -- `log4j-1.2.14.jar`,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

when executes junit test have below error info

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/foo/Documents/logs/info.log (No such file or directory)
...
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
...
```

I'd like to set breakpoint in `LogManager.java` 122 line, but it cannot.
[image]

It is strange that , I could successfully set a breakpoint in other part of the same class. Then I found 122 line is in a static block code.

```
static {...}
```

It seems if a line in static block code , it cannot enable breakpoint here.

So why is this?

Comment: Eclipse IDE can put breakpoints in static block codes in general (I just tried here successfully). What were the exact steps you tried to reach this file and put breakpoint on it?

Comment: Just create a maven project then add dependency -- `log4j-1.2.14.jar`, then open `Open Type` window, input `LogManger`, then go to 122 line, then double click in the left side.

Answer (score 1):

Late, but maybe still helpful to some. I had a similar experience as the OP, but then noticed that Eclipse actually did set a breakpoint. Not a line breakpoint at the place where I had clicked, though, but a class breakpoint marked in the editor at the beginning of the class, which was quite a bit above the line I was interested in.